# passar objetos de uma class para outra

Tags: java

Eu tenho os seguintes objetos na classe Game como é que eu chamo estes objetos na classe `Main`?

```
team1=new Team(t1, t2, t3);
team2=new Team(e1, e2, e3);
```

Comment: A todos os moderadores, eu sei que parece uma pergunta simples, deveriamos ter uma resposta para ela já dentro do SO. Mas não consegui encontrar uma para demonstrar como duplicata, então tomei a liberdade de responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras.

Uma delas é utilizar um construtor na sua classe `Main`:

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main(new Team(), new Team());
    }
}

public class Main {

    Team teamUm;
    Team teamDois;

    public Main(Team teamUm, Team teamDois) {
        this.teamUm = teamUm;
        this.teamDois = teamDois;
    }
}
```

Outra forma é por métodos set, invocados dentro da `Game`:

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setTeamUm(new Team());
        main.setTeamDois(new Team());
    }
}

public class Main {

    Team teamUm;
    Team teamDois;

    public void setTeamUm(Team teamUm) {
        this.teamUm = teamUm;
    }

    public void setTeamDois(Team teamDois) {
        this.teamDois = teamDois;
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude!